# How to use full stops with initials?

Tags: punctuation

For my project I need to write the initials DMRD which stands for discipline, maturity, Remember Death, (originally I was just going to use DMD for discipline, maturity and death- however it is a sexual innuendo) would it be appropriate to write it as D.M.RD. Or D.M.RD without the final full stop and also should the r be capitalised? Thank you :)

Comment: Generally you don't use periods with acronyms.

Comment: Such matters are largely a matter of style. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, adopt a [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) appropriate to your audience and tastes and be consistent in its application.

Comment: If I see *DMD* I think of type of dental degree; there are [plenty of non-sexual meanings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMD). If you're writing for a professional audience, there's no need to go to such lengths to avoid potentially embarrassing interpretations, as context should be sufficient to avoid giggles. My hometown's entertainment district bills itself as DTF, my church has a ministry called CYA, there're not one but two major U.S. corporations named BJ's, and a major piece of U.S. employment legislation is known as FML. I will grant that the USAF at the Dover Air Show is indeed US AF.

Comment: @choster Reminds me of the story Frederick Forsyth recounted once about the effort to coordinate the intelligence efforts of MI6 and 5...the title Strategic Head of Intelligence Targeting was suggested for the director, but then nobody wanted to be known as the SHIT of Whitehall...

Comment: @Cascabel There are certainly limits. As [widely reported](https://thehill.com/blogs/blog-briefing-room/news/justice-antonin-scalia-gmu-law-school-acronym-controversy-assol-asslaw), George Mason University had to revisit the plan to rename its law school the Antonin Scalia School of Law (ASSoL or ASSLaw) to honor the late Supreme Court Justice. I hope they did not have too many sweatshirts made before Twitter gently brought the matter to their attention. It's just the Antonin Scalia Law School now.

Answer (score -1):

> For my project I need to write the initials DMRD which stands for discipline, maturity, Remember Death

**First off**, you *don't* need those initials. In fact, you need to *not* use them. A series should have terms with identical grammatical roles. It shouldn't have two nouns and a verb phrase.

**Second**, even though `Discipline, Maturity, & Remembering Death` or `To Remember Death` works grammatically, they're both so awkward that you should just think of them as wrong too. [Parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar)) prefers using identical formats in a series. `Discipline, Maturity, & Death` was far better. Whatever sexual connotation [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=DMD) might give it isn't part of [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/DMD) or the general culture. It's not as if you're carefully analyzing something like "POOP" or "IANAL" where some readers wouldn't be able to keep a straight face.

**On the other hand**, language aside, your categories seem badly considered. Death is the act or state of being dead. *Remembering* and being mindful of death is simply part of maturity... as is having discipline. It seems very likely that you don't need three terms or an acronym at all. If you do, you're probably stating your categories badly.

> should the r be capitalised?

Yes, if you were using that word.

> would it be appropriate to write it as D.M.RD.[?]

No. That should indicate that RD (impossibly) were the first two letters of the third term.

> [o]r D.M.RD without the final full stop[?]

No. That is simply incorrect in English, although common in East Asian languages. It's fine to use no stops at all, though, which is what you should do in a case like this where you're unsure about the details.

Comment: Does the downvoter mind *explaining* what they think the problem is?

Comment: (I didn't downvote, although it is tempting.) You make a number of assertions that appear to be wrong. For example, what rule says that an acronym (or any series of terms) must have the same grammatical function? I can readily think of several common acronyms where that is not the case.

Comment: @JamesRandom Acronyms don't need to be series or to use similar grammatical terms. Series do need to and I'd be curious what your counterexamples would be.

Comment: @Ily thanks for the reply what would you suggest is better I chose discipline as in sticking to a plan regardless of emotions, maturity as being wise and not extreme like a mature wise person would not open their mouth before they speak for example and death as in memento Mori- what would you suggest is a better combination thanks :)

Comment: @MatthewWynne-Jones All of those are examples of maturity... so why do you think you need to talk about them separately?

Comment: ah yeah I suppose I do see your point, how many different aspects of maturity do you think there is? Also I have 3 words I have to use up so if that’s only going to be one what are other virtues that could go on there as every one I’ve got could be classed as either discipline which is maturity or maturity itself. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't know what your assignment is. Maybe explain and ask for help as a new question here or at http://ell.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @lly oh okay thanks, I've designed a ring and we have to have a meaning behind the ring, so the ring I designed is a signet with 3 stripes in the corner and then I plan to engrave on the underside the initials of the meaning of the ring with 3 virtues representing each line, problem is I can't think of any that would not just be classed as maturity. Thanks :)

Comment: @Ily Do you think maturity and then slow improvement would work well together so like it’s okay as long as the general trend is moving forward- Thanks and sorry for so many questions I will ask no more. :/